# Remap arrow key to different shortcut

Tags: keyboard, macvim

I am used to vim and like to move with <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>. I would like to avoid switching to the arrow keys when I am in a text field for example.

Is there a way to remap the following keys in all application on **Mac OS X**, so that:

<kbd>←</kbd> can also be triggered by <kbd>OPTION</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd>

<kbd>↓</kbd> can also be triggered by <kbd>OPTION</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>

<kbd>↑</kbd> can also be triggered by <kbd>OPTION</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>

<kbd>→</kbd> can also be triggered by <kbd>OPTION</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to remap keys.

> A powerful and stable keyboard customizer for OS X.

[This page](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html) details how to add custom behaviors.

Comment: Can anyone please share the relevant config to get this done?

Comment: I second this. I downloaded Karabiner, but couldn't get it to work on my own.

Comment: The linked page is not available

Answer (score 0):

Just done using [Better Touch Tool](https://folivora.ai/) for osx. It features a wweet options to sync your settings online. When it comes to browsing, it doesn't beat [vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en). I'm using both

Answer (score 0):

After installing [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) and giving required permissions, go to "Complex Modifications" tab on the left and click the "Add your own rule" button. Then paste this code:

```
{
"description": "Remap arrow keys to Option+JKLI",
"manipulators": [
    {
        "from": {
            "key_code": "i",
            "modifiers": {
                "mandatory": [
                    "option"
                ]
            }
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "key_code": "up_arrow"
            }
        ],
        "type": "basic"
    },
    {
        "from": {
            "key_code": "j",
            "modifiers": {
                "mandatory": [
                    "option"
                ]
            }
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "key_code": "left_arrow"
            }
        ],
        "type": "basic"
    },
    {
        "from": {
            "key_code": "k",
            "modifiers": {
                "mandatory": [
                    "option"
                ]
            }
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "key_code": "down_arrow"
            }
        ],
        "type": "basic"
    },
    {
        "from": {
            "key_code": "l",
            "modifiers": {
                "mandatory": [
                    "option"
                ]
            }
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "key_code": "right_arrow"
            }
        ],
        "type": "basic"
    }
]
}
```

Feel free to change to the keys you want. This remaps the arrow keys to Option+JKLI